# Where do maven jboss plugin deploy

Tags: maven, jboss

I am using maven and jboss plugin. When I run this command
mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy

I will deploy in currently running jboss but I want to know which jar file it deploy..jar file generated in target folder or jar file in local repository?

Answer (score 0):

By default it gets the bits from `target` folder. Look at [targetDir](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html#targetDir) property of the plugin.

You can find the details in the [plugin documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/).